# Rx of IR is not working with SSM3K37FSLF MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, infrared

We are developing an IR circuit on our Device. The IR circuit which we are using is shown here, we are giving 2.5 V to the circuit and our controller also works on the same 2.5 V. Previously we were using the **IRFML8244TRPbF** but we switched due to its higher power consumption and because it was not cost effective.

We are currently using the [**SSM3K37FSLF** (SoT-416) MOSFET](https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Toshiba/SSM3K37FSLF?qs=zPgndZZmKGa14u3nO8Srzw%3D%3D) but it is not working/receiving anything on the pin. What should we do next? Why is it not working with this MOSFET?

[image]

Comment: That's not a very good design basically. You should use an op-amp to gain linearity and possible wired as a TIA to obtain high speed performance. Have you thought about simulating your circuit rather than saying it is not working/receiving anything.

Comment: Photodiodes work terribly that way. It's not the MOSFET. You need amplification that does not load down the photodiode. Did you do any research about photodiode circuits before building this one? You might be able to get away with that type of circuit with a phototransistor, but not a photodiode.

Comment: @Andyaka Our device is battery operated and where device's long duration matters.

Comment: your question is frowned upon by moderators on this site as it is a shopping question, but I don't mind if you can define what gain you think you need.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the data sheets of the two devices,
https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_IRFML8244_DataSheet_v01_01_EN-1732713.pdf
and
https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/408/SSM3K37FS_datasheet_en_20140301-963970.pdf
the Gate Threshold voltages are 1.35 - 2.35V (@ \$I_{ds} = 10\mu A\$) and 0.35 to 1V (@ \$I_{ds} = 1mA\$) respectively. OK, they are measured at different currents. So I would suggest you either revert to the previous Mos-FET or possibly recalculate the R17 / R9 / R43 network.

--Addendum--

1. With the original components, calculate the gate voltage when dark. It should be above the  \$ V_{th}  max\$ (1V). Easy calculation, it's a simple voltage divider as the photodiode is effectively an open circuit.
2. Either directly measure or calculate the photocurrent required to get the MOS-FET to turn off, that is \$V_{gs} \lt  V_{th} min\$ (0.35V)
3. Do the same calculations in reverse with \$V_{th}\$ for the new device but the same photocurrent.

Note that with the new MOS-FET the maximum \$V_{th}\$ (2.35V) is very close to VCC (2.5V) and it may never turn on. Have you taken the possible spread in \$V_{th}\$ into account?

Comment: The main reason  we dropped IRFML8244TRPbF is  because of its pricing we are looking for cost effective MOSFET similar to old one. Our Transmitter circuit is working good with new MOSFET, I changed the R17 Value to 3.9k Resistor and it still not worked. Is there any good alternative to IRFML8244TRPbF  ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: While selecting the New MOS-FET I guess we missed out the  Vth value or we thought it will work fine with new MOS-FET.

Comment: If we want to use the same MOSFET then what changes we have to do ?

Comment: As your \$V_{cc}\$ is very close to the maximum possible \$V_{th}\$ of your selected MOS-FET it is not suitable for your application. You cannot use it as it stands. You would have to either increase the \$V_{cc}\$ to, say, at least 5V or pick a different MOS-FET with a much lower maximum \$V_{th}\$. 
Is saving £0.07 that vital to your business model?
Your comment "looking for cost effective MOSFET similar to old one." the trouble is that your choice is not similar enough.

Comment: The Vth what you are referening is for the old MOS-FET  IRFML8244TRPbF it has Vgs from 1.35v to 2.35V and new MOS-FET it has from 0.35V to 1V.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some CMOS logic buffers or inverting gates, you can make a better amplifier using negative feedback ratio for gain such as 10k~100k in and 10M feedback on 2V then add offset to input above  threshold with > 100k pullup.  The RdsOn of your FETs were x mohm to > 1Ohm difference. Using 3.6V CMOS of 74ALCxx shud work at 2.5V. So R7,R9,R43 could initially be 100k, 10k,open and 100k feedback with output load > 10k  or leave as is 10k,1k,10k with 1M feedback

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foQZ80.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That is wonderful explanation. Our device is battery operated and it need to work for more than 5yrs with same battery. actually we switched to SSM3K37FSLF from IRFML8244TRPbF the only reason is pricing of the components.

Comment: Considering the relative cost of 5 cents vs 13 cents, what is your budget and MOQ?

Comment: MOQ would be 1k quantity. is there other MOSFET which will work same as IRFML8244TRPbF ? We are looking for it. I thought SSM3K37FSLF will works for us but it is not working on our existing circuit.

Comment: I guess you do not understand how gain works inverse to threshold and RdsOn

Comment: Sorry I don't know exactly

Comment: Then I guess you do not know how much gain you need and with only 2.5V avail. you need a tight range of low threshold Vgs(th) ~ 1V and how all the wrong R values reduces gain. Basically you need a designer to tell you the details or read about it.

Comment: We dont want to add OP-AMP or Complex Circuitry in our IR Section. We want to use it as Simple becaus eour device is battery operated. If we keep new MOSFET what values will be good for the Device to Receive the data on RX Pin. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My cct is neither complex, high current nor an op amp.  Use the original FET , its available cheaper if you search in HK  but for data I would suggest the IRDA Rx IC's only, but then you have no specs so better advice is not possible. Edit your question